# Loop in opposite directions with Table

Tags: list-manipulation

If one has only initial data `f[x2, x1]` for `x1 = 0` and `x2` = `0`, `0.1`, `0.2`, `...`, `1`. Is there a neat method to loop with the initial data in two opposite directions of `x1` instead of separately running

```
Table[f[x2, x1], {x1, 0, 5, 0.1}, {x2, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

and

```
Table[f[x2, x1], {x1, 0, -5, -0.1}, {x2, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

then combining the data.

Note that the sequencing must start from `x1=0` and then go to the opposite directions.

Comment: Your edit is not particularly clear. Include the code that you are currently using to combine the two tables and whose results you want to duplicate in another manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the ranges beforehand and then feed that to `Table`:

```
res = Table[
   f[x2, x1],
   {x1, Join[Range[0, 5, 0.1], Range[-0.1, -5, -0.1]]},
   {x2, 0, 1, 0.1}
   ];
```

Comment: Unless order of the sequencing is an issue, combining the ranges is just `Table[f[x2, x1], {x1, -5, 5, 0.1}, {x2, 0, 1, 0.1}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon no, the key point is that the sequencing must start from `x1=0` and then go to two opposite directions. I am testing the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Join`

```
Join[
Table[f[x2, x1], {x1, 0, 5, 0.1}, {x2, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
Table[f[x2, x1], {x1, -.1, -5, -0.1}, {x2, 0, 1, 0.1}]
]
```

Comment: Modify one of the tables (see my edit)

Comment: your method is basically the same as C.E.'s. I accepted the latter since it gives the right range first and is neater.